# Sql statement JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite

I see the statement in executeSql like below:

```
addTodo: function (text) {
        app.db.transaction(function (tx) {
            var ts = new Date();
            tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO todo(todo, added_on) VALUES (?,?)", [text, ts], app.onSuccess, app.onError);
        });
    },
```

My question is: what does the " VALUES (?,?) " mean?

Answer (score 1):

Those are parameters that will be properly prepared and substituted by the array argument following the SQL statement.

So

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO todo(todo, added_on) VALUES (?,?)", ['do this', '10/05/2014']);
```

will result in

```
INSERT INTO todo(todo, added_on) VALUES ('do this', '10/05/2014')
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a [prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), which you should use to prevent [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). E.g.

```
var text = "foo";
var ts = "bar";
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO todo(todo, added_on) VALUES (?,?)", [text, ts]);
```

is the same as:

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO todo(todo, added_on) VALUES ('foo','bar')");
```